# Illegal string offset 'result' in php echo

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
function RetrieveAllPages() {
    $dir = '../pages';
     $root = scandir($dir); 
     $result = array();
    foreach($root as $value){ 
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {
            continue;
        } 
        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {
            $result[]="$dir/$value";
            continue;
        } 
        foreach(find_all_files("$dir/$value") as $value){ 
            $result[]=array('filename'  => $value,);
        } 

    } 
    print_r ($result);
    var_dump($result);
    return $result; 
}


<?php
     //echo'<select>';
     foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $value){
     //echo "<option value='".$value['rolename']."'>".$value['rolename']."</option>";
     echo'<input  type="checkbox" value='.$value['result'].' name='.$value['result'].'/>';
     }  
     //echo'</select>';
?>
```

getting this kind of error in php the code is above i have research and cant find any source that fits solution..any suggestion or idea is appreaciated

`UPDATE`

```
function RetrieveAllPages() {
    $result = array();
    $dir = "../pages";
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
    }
    print_r ($result);
    var_dump($result);
    return $result; 
}
```

result is `Array ( ) array(0) { }`

Comment: do you mean `$value['filename']`? there is no index `result` defined in any place in your array. `$value['filename']` will also generate warnings as you have some indexes defined as string `$result[]="$dir/$value";`

Comment: what does this `find_all_files` do? search files inside directory?

Comment: @bansi i want to make the file to be the name in the check box when i do print_r it prints all the files a result, but in the inbox it does not have text but the error please explain your comment a bit more i cant understand i am currently doing tutorials in this one so i am having problems

Comment: you are trying to use a string as a full array...

Comment: @Ghost http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php this is the tutorial i am working on it is int number 6 `kodlee at kodleeshare dot net's` solution

Comment: what is the output of `print_r ($result);`?

Comment: @Dinesh it is an array when i print it it look like this one `Array ( [0] => ../pages/admin.php [1] => ../pages/changepassword.php [2] => ../pages/dashboard.php [3] => ../pages/error.php [4] => ` this is array right?

Comment: @bansi `Array ( [0] => ../pages/admin.php [1] => ../pages/changepassword.php [2] => ../pages/dashboard.php [3] => ../pages/error.php [4] => ../pages/lock.php [5] => ../pages/logout.php [6] => ../pages/permission.php ) array(7) { [0]=> string(18) "../pages/admin.php" [1]=> string(27) "../pages/changepassword.php" [2]=> string(22) "../pages/dashboard.php" [3]=> string(18) "../pages/error.php" [4]=> string(17) "../pages/lock.php" [5]=> string(19) "../pages/logout.php" [6]=> string(23) "../pages/permission.php" } `

Comment: The function in the manual works. try using that

Comment: @I--I no need for that initial loop, use that function alone since it gets the files recursively

Comment: you don't want recursively? then why are you calling `find_all_files`?

Comment: @bansi i tried the one you said to use the function i updated my answer but i get 0 array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to list files recursively you can use this.

```
function RetrieveAllPages() {
    $dir = '../pages';
    $root = scandir($dir); 
    $result = array();
    foreach($root as $value){ 
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {
            continue;
        } 
        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {
            $result[]="$dir/$value";
        }
        //Note: removed the recursive call
    } 
    print_r ($result);
    var_dump($result);
    return $result; 
}

 //echo'<select>';
 foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $value){
 //echo "<option value='".$value['rolename']."'>".$value['rolename']."</option>";
 // Note $value contains the filename!!!
 echo'<input  type="checkbox" value='.$value.' name='.$value.'/>' ;
 }  
 //echo'</select>';
```

Here is another method which is much shorter! uses [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
 $all_files = array_filter(scandir('../pages'),function($v){return(!($v === '.' || $v === '..'));});
 foreach ($all_files as $value){
     echo'<input  type="checkbox" value='.$value.' name='.$value.'/>' . $value .'<br/>';
 }
```

Comment: the second solution i want to ask about it..im still working to undertstand accepted answer but when i tried this one it work but i get error in `foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $value){` `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` when i use this solution it is only pure string?please explain a bit

Comment: The second method don't need `RetrieveAllPages` function. What it does is get the directory `scandir('../pages')` and remove the `.` and `..` using array_filter function and return the file list. Note this don't take care of if the item is directory. it is left for you to check.

Comment: thanks for explanation i will use this one much easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `Illegal offset` error because of the way you have defined the function `RetrieveAllPages()`. From the code, it basically scans a root folder for files and directories. If it encounters a directory, it tries to find all the files in that directory and pushes them into the `result` array which you return.

If you notice the output when you print the `result` array it would look something like this (just an example):

```
 Array ( [0] => foo.jpg [1] => bar.txt [2] => Array ( [filename] => Testfile.pdf ) )
```

Now that you have an idea of what your function returns, let's get back to the `echo` statement:

```
foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $value){
   //Here the $value could be either string of the form root/foo etc or 
     echo $value; //String of file directly found in root directory

   //It would be of the form of an array where you would get file names by doing something like:
    echo $value[0]['filename']; //from the nested array

 }
```

In any case, you are not using the string offset `result` anywhere in the array that you create in `RetrieveAllPages()`. The only string offset you use is `filename`. That is probably why you get this error when you try to create checkboxes out of these values. The way you handle this two kinds of values in your returned array is completely upto you.

*Sidenote* - The way you save your values, it's pretty likely that your function will return a nested array. One workaround could be if you, come across a directory instead of a file just prefix the string to the file names found in that directory instead of creating nested arrays with the prefix `filename`. It would greatly simplify your `echo` statements where you create the `HTML` checkboxes.

Like I said, the implementation is upto you and depends on what you are trying to achieve ultimately. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.